# Adding Missing Constraints might not work

Tags: ios, xcode, constants

Is there something I can do like the symbols in blue as the picture below for 'Adding Missing Constraints" and "Clean Constraints"?

I have lots of 'View Controller's .. some of them are small where I can go to Resolve Auto Layout Issues' or 'Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues' and I can do something there, but if my 'View Controller' has many text and pictures, the 'Resolve Auto Layout Issues' opens after 1 hour or even two and never sometimes! (I'm not joking).

Is there any idea?

Thank you in advance.

[image: Picture]

Comment: it seem to be your system problem.For complex UI machine take some time. How much memory is for your machine??

Comment: I hope this is the one .. http://oi68.tinypic.com/119v8f5.jpg

Comment: yes. I am using 16 GB still sometimes it will take some time.

Comment: I'll sit more than 3 hours then :/ .. thank you :)

Comment: File a bug at Apple.